# MVC Multiple MembershipProviders - one of them WebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I know how I can switch between multiple MembershipProviders, if they are of the type Membership, like:

```
  MembershipProvider provider;
  if ( username.Text.StartsWith("G\") then
    provider = Membership.Providers["GlobalProvider"];
  else
    provider = Membership.Providers["StandardProvider"];

  if ( provider.ValidateUser( ...
```

But I have troubles if ONE of them is the WebSecurity Provider, which VS2012 uses in the Internet-Template, which is an instance of ExtendedMembershiprovider.
I would like to use this one for Membership/Access to an Administration-area of a website, whereas the rest of the site uses a Third-Party custom membershipprovider for access of users to certain other areas.

So I think it boils down to the question:

How can I switch between instance Membership and ExtendedMembership?

Answer (score 0):

I could find out current provider using

```
    // Current provider
    var provider = Membership.Provider;

    // List of providers
    var providers = Membership.Providers;
```

You can also check whether current provider is derived from ExtendedMembershipProvider or not using:

```
ExtendedMembershipProvider extendedMembershipProvider = Membership.Provider as ExtendedMembershipProvider;
```

Not sure this is what you want, thought might be useful for you.